# When choosing a site to plant a black walnut what should I look for?

Tags: walnut

I was asked to install a black walnut tree along a fairly flat creek bed. What should I look for when planting the tree?

Comment: Is this creek bed flowing with water?

Comment: I know this isn't what you are asking, and I don't want to come across sounding snarky, but look for a Sycamore rather than a Black Walnut. Black Walnuts will tend to prevent other things from growing underneath and will  get very messy with all of their nuts. If harvesting the nuts is the point then ignore this pre-coffee advice.

Comment: ...and if you are planting the Black Walnut for the nuts, make sure you like the flavor first. Black walnuts have a very distinctive, strong flavor. Hickory nuts and Butternuts are both also native to this part of the country and, in my opinion, have better flavor. (Although butternuts are affected by a canker disease, so read up on that before planting one.)

Comment: Yes, the creek bed has water,as well as a main propane pipeline.

Comment: @ThatIdiot your question doesn't apply, because my mom wants it, not me, and the only thing growing there is tall grass.

Comment: @michelle my uncle grows them already.

Comment: @blackthumb That Idiot's comment is still useful, though, since it tells you to plant it away from other plants you want to grow (as well as areas you'll some day want plants). Maybe it would be great to plant in a field of morning glory. :)